# Is there a way could check if an embed is a specific colour or not?

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is what I have been able to come up with after a lot of head scratching and being annoyed but lo and behold, it doesn't work.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.channel.id == "the-channel-id-here"):
        embeds = message.embeds
        if not embeds:
            return
        else:
            embed = (message.embeds)[0]
            if (embed.color == 4caf50 or e53935):
                print('I got that')
            else:
                return

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

`discord.py` always returns a `Color` object, rather than an `integer`, so what you're comparing right now is an instance of `Color` (as defined [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/69bdc3a1849407f64ef93bd2e5119e54d6cd2208/discord/colour.py#L30) by the way) and a number. The `Color` object has an attribute `value` that returns an integer representation of the colour though, so you can use that to compare it to a number instead.

This code snippet should work:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.channel.id == "the-channel-id-here"):
        embeds = message.embeds
        if not embeds:
            return
        else:
            embed = (message.embeds)[0]
            if (embed.color.value == 4caf50 or embed.color.value == e53935):
                print('I got that')
            else:
                return

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Do note that I modified your `if` expression slightly, your use of `or` was wrong, you DO have to repeat `embed.color.value` again for the comparison to work!